# Solving $z^4 + 2z^3 + 6z - 9 = 0$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve $z^4 + 2z^3 + 6z - 9 = 0$.

$z$ is a complex number.

I usually can solve those equations when they are of second degree.

I don't know what to do, breaking out $z$ doesn't help...

**EDIT:** Sorry I forgot to mention that $z$ has a solution where $\Re(z) = 0$.

Comment: There is a formula for equations of (up to) fourth degree, but you don't want to use it unless you have to. If you can guess a solution $a$ by trying (like $z=1$ in this case :-) you can divide the polynomial by $(z-a)$ (polynomial division), resulting in a product $(z-a) p(z)$. The degree of $p$ is then smaller than the degree of the original polynomial, and with some luck you can continue like this till you end up with $(z-a)(z-b) q(z)$ with $q$ of degree 2....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, $z=1$ is one of the roots (always check whether 1 or -1 is one of the roots, it's worth it). So, to calculate other factors, you should calculate:
 $$\frac{z^4+2z^3+6z-9}{z-1}$$

Which would be $z^3+3z^2+3z+9$ by polynomial division. Now, it's easy to factorize $(z+3)$.
$$z^2(z+3)+3(z+3)=(z+3)(z^2+3)$$

To satisfy the condition $\Re(z) = 0$,  you should find the values of $z$ in $z^2+3$ ($z=\pm i \sqrt3$).

Comment: Did you mean $(z+3)$ instead of $(z-3)$?

Comment: @Tim: Right, I made a small mistake there. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The complex number $z = c$ is a solution to the equation $f(z) = 0$ (also called a zero or root of $f(z)$) if and only if $(z-c)$ is a factor of $f(z)$.  The proof of this statement follows easily by adapting the Euclidean algorithm which concerns finding the greatest common divisor of integers to finding the greatest common divisor of functions.  A proof of this statement would be easy enough that I could add it to the post if you like.

At any rate, use this idea and try to find a root to the equation $z^4 +2z^3 + 6z -9 = 0$.  Finding a root then gives a factor, and reduces the degree of the polynomial you want to factor by $1$.

Now there are many ways to find the zeroes of $f(z)$.  In the simplest cases, you can simply guess and check for solutions.  The obvious candidates to check for zeroes are $z = 1, z = -1, z = 2, z= -2$, etc.  Note that $z = 0$ is a zero if and only if $f(z)$ has no constant term.  One of the more useful tests for finding roots of polynomials is the [Rational Root Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).  Other known methods for finding zeroes of polynomials include [completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square#Solving_quadratic_equations) (for quadratic functions), using the [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function), or using the [quartic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation), though the cubic and quartic formulae are a bit unwieldy in practice.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: @Dimme, did you forget to say "thank you"?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: are there any rational roots? If $z=\frac{n}{m}$ is a rational root in reduced form, then $n$ must be a divisor of $\pm 9$, and $m=1$.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Your edit does not change my answer. As Javaman points out, if $a$ is a root, then $z-a$ is a factor of your polynomial. In this case, you can use my hint to find two rational roots $a$ and $b\in\mathbb{Q}$, and then factor your polynomial $p(z)$ as $(z-a)(z-b)q(z)$, where $q(z)$ is quadratic (and therefore easy to factor).

Answer (score 1):

The given information means there is a solution of the form $it$ with $t$ real.  Then $-it$ is also a solution (since all coefficients are real).  Plugging these two solutions in and using a little algebra you should be able to solve for $t$ and therefore find a quadratic factor $z^2 + t^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the highroad here is to recognise the factor $z^2+3$:

$ (z^4-9) + (2z^3 + 6z) = (z^2+3)(z^2-3) + (z^2+3)(2z) = (z^2+3)(z^2+2z-3)$
$= (z+i\sqrt{3})(z-i\sqrt{3})(z-1)(z+3)$

Comment: And is there some align* or eqnarray environment possible with mathjax? My attempts were futile.

Comment: assuming all the algebra before is correct, you factored $z^2 + 2z - 3$ incorrectly. It should be $(z-1)(z+3)$.

Comment: Would you really have to assume that? :P But I editted the signs, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[The Quartic Formula](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac12/fac12.html) can be very useful to solve this.
But there is an alternate way, which my lecturer suggested me : Summing and Subtracting some powers of $z$ to make expression factorable.
For example $z^4+2z^3+6z-9=0$ can be factorized as:

> $z^4+(3z^3-z^3)+(3z^2-3z^2)+(9z-3z)-9=0$
>   $(z^4+3z^3+3z^2+9z)-(z^3+3z^2+3z+9)=0$
>   $z(z^3+3z^2+3z+9)-(z^3+3z^2+3z+9)=0$
>   $z(z^2(z+3)+3(z+3))-(z^2(z+3)+3(z+3))=0$
>   $(z-1)(z+3)(z^2+3)=0$.

Thus, $z^2+3=0$ or $z=\pm i \sqrt{3}$ are the required solutions for your given conditions.

Comment: This method seems very interesting but I don't quite understand how you pick your numbers. Do you want to explain?

Comment: I think, I am not a good person to explain it. This is matter of practice. Point that is kept in mind:
> You have to break whole expression in two or more parts each having 'some terms' common.